# Bmp to same dimensions pdf

Tags: pdf, dimensions, bmp

I have a bmp file (or it could be any image file type).

How can I convert it to a same dimensions pdf?
(because online converters I have found tend to convert it to a full a4 dimensions pdf, where the picture is somewhere in the page and the rest of the page is blank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use this online converter :
[Link to a pdf converter](http://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf)
I tried it with an image and it did not give me a A4 size.

With LaTeX you can create a document containing :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{file.png}

\end{document}
```

and compile it with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using LaTeX (that's why I asked this question) in Windows. I just tried the link that you gave me and it works :) ;)